# Unable to establish SSL connection when downloading from EarthData using wget

Tags: wget

Him I am trying to download FLDAS 0.01 degree data from earth data using wget.

data link: https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/datasets/FLDAS_NOAH001_G_CA_D_001/summary

I followed all the instruction given there to Install wget on windows 11. I downloaded the subset data files in text format and linked it to wget command for multiple files download.

issue: Some files are being downloaded fine while some are not, and error message says unable to establish SSL connection.

Here is sample from the terminal

```
--2023-10-26 08:44:11--  https://hydro1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/daac-bin/OTF/HTTP_services.cgi?FILENAME=%2Fdata%2FFLDAS%2FFLDAS_NOAH001_G_CA_D.001%2F2009%2F01%2FFLDAS_NOAH001_G_CA_D.A20090115.001.nc&FORMAT=bmM0Lw&DATASET_VERSION=001&LABEL=FLDAS_NOAH001_G_CA_D.A20090115.001.nc.SUB.nc4&VERSION=1.02&VARIABLES=Rainf_f_tavg%2CRainf_tavg%2CTair_f_tavg&SERVICE=L34RS_LDAS&SHORTNAME=FLDAS_NOAH001_G_CA_D&BBOX=22.953%2C59.59%2C38.422%2C79.629
Connecting to hydro1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (hydro1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.99|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
--2023-10-26 08:44:11--  https://hydro1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov/daac-bin/OTF/HTTP_services.cgi?FILENAME=%2Fdata%2FFLDAS%2FFLDAS_NOAH001_G_CA_D.001%2F2009%2F01%2FFLDAS_NOAH001_G_CA_D.A20090116.001.nc&FORMAT=bmM0Lw&DATASET_VERSION=001&LABEL=FLDAS_NOAH001_G_CA_D.A20090116.001.nc.SUB.nc4&VERSION=1.02&VARIABLES=Rainf_f_tavg%2CRainf_tavg%2CTair_f_tavg&SERVICE=L34RS_LDAS&SHORTNAME=FLDAS_NOAH001_G_CA_D&BBOX=22.953%2C59.59%2C38.422%2C79.629
Connecting to hydro1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov (hydro1.gesdisc.eosdis.nasa.gov)|198.118.197.99|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 17577253 (17M) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: 'FLDAS_NOAH001_G_CA_D.A20090116.001.nc.SUB.nc4'

FLDAS_NOAH001_G_CA_D.A2009011 100%[=================================================>]  16.76M   733KB/s    in 41s

2023-10-26 08:44:58 (416 KB/s) - 'FLDAS_NOAH001_G_CA_D.A20090116.001.nc.SUB.nc4' saved [17577253/17577253]
```

Why is it skipping few files and is there a way to download just missing files by executing the command again? Or a workaround as I just want the consistent data.

I am not familiar with wget nor I have any idea what it is. So apologies